# Returning top value of column from range in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split, vlookup, spreadsheet, flatten

Say I had a list like this.

```
Group 1     Group 2
Edward, C   Kate, A
Mark, F     Ava, Z
```

Now, in a different column =IF(COUNTIF('Gender'!$A$2:$B$3, "Kate, A"), "", "") is my current formula. I would like to make the first set of empty speech marks return Group 1 or Group 2 depending what column it is. I still require the COUNTIF because my actual sheet has values which will not be contained in either column.

Thanks.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I've quickly created a small example which mimics what im trying to do. I can't share the exact copy of the original sheets because it contains a large number of full names + personal information.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U42E47D1dkeT1G26k7Uiy_s_IHUBKjRjGdug72axfWU/edit#gid=1621737451

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U42E47D1dkeT1G26k7Uiy_s_IHUBKjRjGdug72axfWU/edit

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP("Kate, A", SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(Gender!A2:B="",,Gender!A2:B&"×"&Gender!A1:B1)), "×"), 2, 0)))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(Groups!B2:C="",,Groups!B2:C&"×"&Groups!A1&"×"&Groups!B1:C1), 
 IF(Groups!F2:G="",,Groups!F2:G&"×"&Groups!E1&"×"&Groups!F1:G1)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1'"&A1&"'"), {2, 3}, 0)))
```

[image]

#### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nsOJkx9UWRwiqe7Jg3JFKncxCQ6QeHN0HmD9PsvjzPc/copy)

Comment: Thanks for helping me! What exactly does the query part do? Sorry, I'm not really familiar with Google Sheets Query Language.

Comment: @Timewarper basically it takes the input and pivots it (distributes it) as you require. the thing is it works with all input values so to filter it down on values you only need (A2:A) we use vlookup

Comment: How could I edit it in the event that the formula is not in B1 and rather E1 or F1?

I'm assuming the query needs to be changed, I understand the rest of it.

Comment: @Timewarper reference of Col1 is the 1st column not necessarily meaning A column. so as it is you can put this formula in E1 or F1. only if you want it in row 2 you will need to change VLOOKUP(A1:A to VLOOKUP(A2:A ...we basically create one single column with FLATTEN which we then SPLIT into 3 columns so Col1, Col2, Col3 references will be always present

Comment: Thanks.
It's working now, for the most part. On one of my sheets, it has run but it was not returning anything on the leftmost column. I tried testing the formula back on the example sheet, and it worked.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U42E47D1dkeT1G26k7Uiy_s_IHUBKjRjGdug72axfWU/edit?usp=sharing

like this. Sorry about all these questions, I'm a bit inexperienced with spreadsheets.

Comment: @Timewarper see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHKIQ.png at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15-KUHij-p0Zb8ZW9vzk26LswUmdZRjXYqlsuLZkJQ3E/edit#gid=1621737451